# OpenApiGenerator Warnings

Tags: java, maven, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am using OpenApiGenerator, and I am generating some types in my pom.xml file using some type mappings, here is an example

```
                <typeMappings>
                    <typeMapping>PdfFileFormat=Flux&lt;DataBuffer&gt; </typeMapping>
                </typeMappings>
```

or like this one :

```
                <typeMappings>
                    <typeMapping>SetOfItels=Set&lt;MyItems&gt;</typeMapping>
                </typeMappings>
```

And When I am generating, I am getting the following warnings :

```
[[1;33mWARNING[m] Unknown type found in the schema: PdfFileFormat
```

So my question is: How can I get rid of these warnings? and I do have a bunch of them

###### openapi-generator version

I am using version **5.4.0**

And Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect syntax. In plugin schema you can see that typeMappings type is list, not map.
So all your custom typeMappings should be comma separated list

```
<typeMappings>Type1=com.example.Type1,Type2=com.example.Type2</typeMappings>
```